# Runtime Data LoadRunner option

Tags: loadrunner

I want to get the Runtime Data tab in LoadRunner. But I am not able to do, I tried in the runtime settings, but no use.

The Runtime Data tab present in image is what I needed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you need to see the runtime data while execution. You can simply go to `View > Debug > Runtime Data`